# Jenkins job: Sonarqube server can not be reached

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

In Jenkins, I created a job to test a Sonarqube configuration, but the job fails with errors. 
I tried several times to solve the problem, but I can't find the solution.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Below, I put the code of the Jenkins build.

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\Jenkins\Jenkins_home\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_3.0.2.656\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\Jenkins\Jenkins_home\jobs\ASDS AnubIs Sonar Test\workspace\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_151 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [https://sonarqube_test_server] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.587s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/123M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at
```

Comment: Can you check that DNS resolution for `sonarqube_test_server` works on your slave ?

Comment: Narrow down on the possibilities.
Are you able to reach the server using curl or equivalent command?
If not, what error code are you getting?
Is the sonar accessible from outside jenkins machine/slave?

Comment: How did you setup you https-configuration? Also check that the user that is executing the job has "Execute Analysis" rights.

Comment: The Sonarqube server (6.7.1) is accessible form outside Jenkins. Also is the configured with "Execute Analysis" rights.

Comment: @WlllemDalen did you find a solution?